# How to update part of the page while browsing records from DB

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I am building a site with PHP & MySQL. Some queries return multiple records. Each record gets a separate page. The user can navigate between pages (records) with arrows.

Till here everything works fine.

But there is something irritating... When the user navigate to other page, the whole page is repainted (header, body, footer etc). I wants to update only the body or even only the images and some relevant text from MySql that belong to the new record, without reloading everything.

Another annoyance which connected: While navigation the new page appears on users' browser from beginning, so users have to scroll down every time they click an arrow.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done some research into this? Do you have an idea of how you plan to tackle this?

Comment: You are talking about AJAX

Comment: Can you give e some insights. I am total beginner..

Comment: or without jQuery http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

Comment: I think this is less a case of rendering and a misunderstanding on what HTTP is and how most websites in the world work.

Comment: @ErezMeoded AJAX = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML, it's not something new but a way to communicate in between server and client. I'm not sure if you can digest this in a short time but if you are really a beginner it might be a lot easier for you to use an iframe that wrap your data so when you click for a new page, it only refreshes the iframe and contents in it.

Comment: @Godinall I'm not sure that the iframe solution are a good idea... Google doesn't like, so SEO in decline... But i'm not totally sure about that.

Comment: @ThibaultM Did you really just say "Google doesn't like iFrames"? Do you not realize what houses Every Single Widget they host? Google is iFrame nuts!

Comment: @Godinall Thanks! please give an answer so I can thumb you up.

Comment: @ThibaultM iframe is not the best solution of course, but makes his life easier other than starting learning how to use AJAX from nil. Besides, it won't affect SEO if you do it in the right way. Same as AJAX.

Comment: @ErezMeoded my comment was meant to help you not to gain reputation on this website. As long as it helps you, you can even close this question. Besides what I said was only a guide not actually an answer.

Comment: @Godinall I am totally impressed! I will learn AJAX and improve the site. currently it is working so I am not in a hurry. Thanks again!

Comment: @ErezMeoded you are quite welcome. I like your attitude to improve a current working website to make it better. Good luck with the learning curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about AJAX
It's a technology doing exactly what you need
 1. You form the page itself - header, footer and a middle container.
Say, it can be `<div id="container"></div>`.
 2. You form an GET or POST request in JavaScript (I recommend jQuery) to a little separate script, say ajax.php. Usually parameters tell it what do fetch and return. Say, an example call would look like `/ajax.php?page=about`
Google `jQuery.ajax`, `jQuery.get` and `jQuery.post` methods on how to do it.
 3. What that script does - it returns the middle of the page content, in clear HTML form.
 4. On successful data load your main JavaScript inserts the content it got into the "container". 
Like, `$("#container").html( content );`

That's basically it!
You will need to change your navigation though from being links like `<a href="...">` to JavaScript, performing AJAX requests to load different content, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make a ajax request without moving away from the current page, and get the response that can be easily displayed on any div inside body.
For further details [jquery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I would suggest op, perhaps, remove this Q b4 it gains to much negativity and also, the op should "research" jQuery ajax, starting with some base tutorials on like CodeProject or something.

Comment: @ErezMeoded I never said he shouldn't ask. But these kinds of questions have a tendency to scoop up downvotes in a hurry and I wouldn't want him to get discouraged from coming here to ask.